# rails base file has function a that calls a function c, but c is defined in two js files. How to resolve this per page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I created a **application_base.js** that has a function:

```
function drawLocations(canvas, blag, blah) {
    //do some stuff
    selectLocations(a_something, b_something);
    //do some stuff
}
```

For Page 1: **page_1.js**

```
function selectLocations(a_something, b_something) {
    //set some selectors on Page 1
}

drawLocations(canvas, blag, blah); //here on page ready
```

For Page 2: **page_2.js**

```
function selectLocations(a_something, b_something) {
    //set some selectors on Page 2
}

drawLocations(canvas, blag, blah); //here on page ready
```

But only the selectLocations function in page_1.js is getting called when drawLocations gets called on either of the page. I'm not sure I understand scoping in js, but I pretty sure it just searches the function and since it's all global scope, it executes when it first finds the function.

How do I make it so that only the selectLocations function on the page that calls drawLocations is called. I've gone through a couple questions here but, couldn't find anything directly relative.

I'm pretty new to js. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are sure that page_1.js is not loaded in case page 2 is requested?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but doesn't rails put miniaturize everything into 1 single file? So everything gets loaded. Now there are 2 functions at global scope so it picks the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first  class citizens in js. I was able to pass selectLocations as a parameter to drawLocations.

```
drawLocations(..., selectLocations){
...
}
```

So, on the page ready page just pass that page's function as a parameter.